# Facebook ads api Custom Audience retention days

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I've create a new CustomAudience, set the retention_days to 1 and added some contacts into it.

I don't see any change to the group after 2 days since I've added the contacts to the group.

Under the "Audience History" I can see my API calls to add and remove specific contacts, but nothing indicates that the contacts added few days ago removed due to the "retention_days" value.

Facebook's Ads API docs doesn't give much information.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking for the Pixel Based Custom Audiences . In that case have you checked if your pixel is already installed on the website ??